# Setting spark running in local multiple threads mode, why only one cpu is running?

Tags: apache-spark

I submit spark job to run in local machine with parameter --master local[6]. however, when I monitor the Spark UI, I found the spark.master is set to local instead of local[6]. I traced cpu status, it also shows only one cup is currently working, details as follows.

```
Tasks: 157 total,   1 running, 155 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 99.7 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  49463808 total, 43074276 used,  6389532 free,   225860 buffers
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,        0 used,  4194300 free.  8510192 cached Mem
```

[image: Spark UI spark.master info]

[image: spark submit command]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is I mistakenly overwrote the parameter by calling setMaster("local") in the program. It runs on multiple cores and the spark.master = local[6] in the spark UI after removing this setMaster() statement.

Comment: If this is the solution for your issue, you might want to put it as final answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to my mind is that you don't really have data in multiple paritions.

if you are doing `sc.parallelize` or `sc.textFile` or similar somewhere in your code, make sure, that you have data in many partitions. you can check it via SparkUI.

If not, please give more details about your job.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I discovered the problem is that I overwrote the property by calling setMaster() in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the master to "local[i]" indicates *i* worker threads, it is not the same as using *i* CPUs.

Comment: That's what Spark's documentation says about master URLS (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls). Its possible to interpret local[3] as running 3 worker threads, which could use just 1 CPU all the same.

Comment: didn't see that part in the document. well, it has "local[K] Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine)." If i smaller than total number of available CUPs, it will make i CPUs. of course, if i larger than that, then, it can only use up to i CPUS.